# Decompiled .class file. Maven, intellij IDEA 2019,3 community v

Tags: java, intellij-idea, openjdk

Создал проект на maven, написал условный класс с использование string, Math. , StringBuolder И тому подобные классы. По нажатию ctrl+ЛКМ (с курсором на String например) - проваливаюсь в документацию Decompiled.
Собственно вопрос: что нужно сделать, что бы по нажатию на ctrl+ЛКМ я мог читать Open source документацию по встроенным классам и методам jdk 11?

Comment: простите, что сразу не уточнил: в open source documentation к каждому классу и методу есть комментарий, который очень помогает сориентироваться и правильно использовать все возможности Intellij И Java

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Решение найдено :)
переустановил jdk 14 с сайта Oracle и указал в idea путь к Src.zip файлу.